# Vim :: How To Disable Swap File for FileType

Tags: vim

I'm attempting to disable swap specifically for text files. However, autocmd attempts are not working correctly. Is it possible to disable swap on a filetype basis?

_vimrc

```
call pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles()
call pathogen#helptags()
call pathogen#infect()
filetype plugin indent on
... 
autocmd FileType text set noswapfile // fails ...
```

Comment: That autocmd works for me in an otherwise empty vimrc. I suspect one of your plugins (loaded by pathogen) is overriding the autocmd. You can check where the option is last set using `:verbose set swapfile?`

Comment: I believe you're correct ... changing _vimrc to ft=text showed noswapfile :: changing it back to ft=vim didn't update even after :source % :: TY